# Get position in array with ng-repeat, ng-model and checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm

I have to ask my users a series of questions and record their responses. There is variety in the questions and the type / amount of possible answers so I am trying to write my code in a way that captures all of the question types. Two example questions are:

what size organization would you prefer?
answer options: 1-10, 11-50, 51-200, 201-500, 501-1,000, 1,001-5,000, 5,001-10,000, 10,000+

What dress code do you prefer?
answer options: casual, business casual, formal

I need to ask the same question to two different users and compare their responses to each other to determine a % match. Since the answers are different, I want to match on position in the array of the chosen answer. That way, I can dynamically build the answer options in the view and use the same matching algorithm for all the questions. user1 answerArray[1,3,5] and user2 ansswerArray[2,3,5] answer 3 matches so give a point. alternatively, user1 answerArray[false, false, true, true, true] and user2 answerArray[true, true, true, false, false] they both picked answer 3 so give a point.

My current approach is trying to use ng-repeat to create a checkbox for each answer, but I'm not sure how to determine which box is checked. I tried using index to get the the position in the repeat loop but it doesn't work and I don't know how to handle passing it into my submit function.

```
form.form-horizontal(ng-submit='answer(not sure what to do with params here)')
    div.form-group(ng-repeat='answer in questionData.answers')
        label.col-xs-3 {{answer}}:
            input(type='checkbox' ng-model='index' ng-change='checked(true, false)')
```

I have read some other answers about combining ng-repeat and ng-model and I can make the array an array of objects, then set ng-model to an object property. That seems like unnecessary transformation of the data. I would be happy to hear alternative solutions.

page looks like this:

```
<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
    <div class="ng-binding ng-scope">What size organization do you prefer?</div>
    <form ng-submit="answer(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)" class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope"><!-- ngRepeat: answer in questionData.answers -->
        <div ng-repeat="answer in questionData.answers" class="form-group ng-scope">
            <label class="col-xs-3 ng-binding">1-10:
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$index" ng-change="checked(true, false)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $index to access the position of the current item in the loop. So you can assign the model value as `answerArray[$index]` so that you will get an array of the results

```
input(type='checkbox' ng-model='answerArray[$index]' ng-change='checked(true, false)')
```

Comment: How do I pass the results into my submit function? If I have something like ng-submit = answers() I am guessing the parameters will be 1,2,3... If I am setting ng-model with $index, but wouldn't that register as a string representation of the number instead of the var represented by ng-model? And how do I deal with passing in variable numbers of parameters?

Comment: @user137717 can you share the generated html sample

Comment: I added an edit to the end of my post. I took a small snippet because I'm using ng-view and I can't find a way to pretty print the output from the Elements tab. Viewing page source only show my layout template. same with postman.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` comes with `$index`. For instance:

```
 <li ng-repeat="page in pages">
            <a ng-class="{ testClass: $index == pageNumber }" ng-click="setPageNumber($index)">{{ page }}</a>
 </li>
```